# Android View Canvas onTouchEvent

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a stupid application where a "`HelloWorld!!`" String drawn using a `Canvas` moves. The position `(x_new, y_new)` of the string is simply its old position `(x_old, y_old)` plus the `(x, y)` returned by an `ACTION_UP` event. The problem is that the event `ACTION_UP` it's not recognized. The `Log.d()` function prints always something like `motionEvent(28254): MotionEvent{4050df70 action=4 x=354.0 y=415.0 pressure=0.20000002 size=0.26666668}` where `action=4` never change. Do you have got any suggestions? Thanks!!

```
class myView extends View {

private Canvas canvas;
    private int x;
private int y;

public HUDView(Context context) {
   super(context);
   this.x=5;
   this.y=5;    

}


protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.canvas=canvas;
    this.canvas.drawText("HelloWorld!!", x, y, mLoadPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
    Log.d("motionEvent", event.toString());
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Log.d("motionEvent", "action_up");
            this.x+=(int)event.getX();
            this.y+=(int)event.getY();
        return true;
    }
    this.postInvalidate();
    return true;
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no need for global variable Canvas(you are drawing on a canvas that's not updating with the view)
2. In the onTouchEven if Action is up you return true without postInvalidating
3. Your constructor has the wrong name

As it stands in the question your code won't run. This should work though

```
class myView extends View {

  private int x;
  private int y;

  public myView (Context context) {
    super(context);
       this.x=5;
       this.y=5;    
  }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
         canvas.drawText("HelloWorld!!", x, y, mLoadPaint);
 }

 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event) {
     super.onTouchEvent(event);
      Log.d ("motionEvent", event.toString());
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Log.d("motionEvent", "action_up");
        this.x+=(int)event.getX();
        this.y+=(int)event.getY();
       }
      this.postInvalidate();
     return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers and sorry for the mistakes! @CarlSaldanha the code doesn't work for me not even with your advices. I still got only 'action=4' motion event

Comment: 'action=4' stands for ACTION_OUTSIDE It means you've made a mistake deploying this view and the action is taking place outside it.

Comment: Read more here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_OUTSIDE

Answer (score 0):

use invalidate post invalidate is used in threads